# STATIC classes vs Local scope classes : FETCHING class

Tags: php, class, static, get, fetch

I am going to build a data fetch class.
However I want to make sure that I am choosing the correct approach.

I (think) I can approach it in two different ways.
One is a local class

```
<?php
$fetch = new FetchClass();
$fetch->FetchPost();
$fetch->FetchGet();
$fetch->FetchSession();
$fetch->All2LocalScope();
?>
```

Very dirty example. But this just sprung into my mind.

Second option is that I make the class static.

```
<?php
FETCH::INIT();
FETCH::FETCHPOST();
FETCH::FETCHGET();
FETCH::FETCHSESSION();
FETCH::ALL2LOCALSCOPE();
?>
```

The last one appeals much more to me because then I can load : `$_SESSION, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE` into one single static class and clean all contents and call upon them whenever and wherever I need them by e.g. : $bicycle = FETCH::POST('bicycle');
And clear the POST, GET contents right away to prevent any accidental quick and dirty `if($_POST['something'] == 'somethingelse'){}`

To me it sounds very nice and bright. But performance wise I have absolutely no clue whether I am choosing the right approach.

Do static classes have any impact on performance?
And the approach as I mentioned it above... Does it appeal to you? And if not. Why?

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of this class is - what's wrong with just using the superglobals directly?

Comment: It should be fine. Most of the large frameworks I have seen, have some sort of a wrapper for things like `$_POST` and `$_GET` with them accessible in all controllers. Perhaps dig through Zend/CakePHP and see what they are doing that you can grab ideas from.

Comment: Performance is absolutely the last thing you should be thinking about here. You need to think about why you are abstracting the superglobals into a class in the first place - what is the abstraction you are trying to achieve? Then you can think about what *architecture* best serves that aim.

Comment: @IMSoP The main idea for doing so is security. Superglobals are nice. But not sanitized... I want to be sure that everything is nice and clean. AND I can predefine what to expect in those variables. For example... $_GET['action'] can only have a certain range of values for example.

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg Sanitization should be relative to the *destination* of your data, not its *source* - that is, it is the responsibility of an HTML view to sanitize for HTML, the responsibility of a DB abstraction layer to sanitize for SQL, etc. Similarly, the list of 'action' values is likely the responsibility of some routing or controller layer, which might later be plugged onto an API with no notion of a query string. **There is no such thing as a string which is "nice and clean".**

Comment: Still something I actually forgot to mention I would love to do in my fetching class is typecasting.. If something is intended an integer I would be certain to receive an integer and not a string.
PHP is very happy to convert everything you got to a string. Especially database entries. (worst part about PHP)

Hence I would like to be certain that elements will remain the datatype intended.

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg "PHP is very happy to convert everything you got to a string." - actually, if you're talking about user input, its vice versa: in HTTP, everything is a string, but PHP is happy to let you write `$_GET['price'] * $_GET['quantity']` as though they were numbers. And again, this is heavily context-specific, and should not be the responsibility of a god-like "make it right" class.